# How to crop area from camera

Tags: ios, swift

I have draw a rectangle with in the native camera view, I'm trying to use it as a guide or crop area to capture only the business card image, I'm unable to crop image from camera native view within drawn rectangle

```swift
extension UIScreen {
    func  fullScreenSquare() -> CGRect {
        var hw:CGFloat = 0
        var isLandscape = false
        if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
            hw = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        }
        else {
            isLandscape = true
            hw = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
        }

        var x:CGFloat = 0
        var y:CGFloat = 0
        if isLandscape {
            x = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2) - (hw / 2)
        }
        else {
            y = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2) - (hw / 2)
        }
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: hw, height: hw/3*2)
    }
    func isLandscape() -> Bool {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width > UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    }
}

func guideForCameraOverlay() -> UIView {
    let guide = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.fullScreenSquare())
    guide.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    guide.layer.borderWidth = 4
    guide.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    guide.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return guide
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if setPhoto == 1 {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
            let size = CGSize(width: 600, height: 400)
            //let imageCroped = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: size)
            let imageCroped = image.crop(to: size)
            frontPhotoImageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: imageCroped as! CGImage)

            setPhoto = 0
            frontPhotoImage.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)


        }
        else {
            // Error message
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    if setPhoto == 2 {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
            backPhotoImageView.image = image

            setPhoto = 0
            backPhotoImage.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        else {
            // Error message
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I expect to have the image from with in the drawn rectangle, but it does not happen.
[I expect to crop the image to the size inside the orange rectangle on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE4m9.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide an example, i.e. expected image and outcome image?

Comment: The image is captured by the camera and is a ID like a business card, passport or a drivers license. I expect to crop the image to eliminate the outside area.

Comment: I mean how the output is different than what you expected? is it shifted, scaled, or what?

Comment: I have uploaded the picture, my expectation is simple I have an orange square and I want this to be guide for the user to frame the id inside this rectangle and only obtain the id without other objects.

Comment: You could use a fullscreen guide (`let guide = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`) that has a mask (`guide.layer.mask =`) to make it mostly black, except for the rectangle part which would be clear.